# Jquery: dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm in need of a dynamic form that will be built from a list of inputs (hidden by default) depending on select input value.

The only problem I face is to show/hide form elements. I have following code:

```
            var form = $("#form");
            var type = $("select[name=type]").val();

            switch(type){
                case 'image':
                    form.html($("#title, #src"));
                    break;
                case 'video':
                    form.html($("#title, #url"));
                    break;
                case 'text':
                    form.html($("#title, #body"));
                    break;
                case 'generate':
                    form.html($("#title, #src));
                    break;
            }
```

My question is: how to add/remove object child elements dynamically? Inputs are stored in separate `<div>` element - I need to add or remove them as child element of `#form` div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `form.append(...)` and the elements will be appended at the end of the form

Comment: I was trying it - the main issue is that I need to hide elements when changing `<select>` value.

Comment: Could you post more of your code? like, are you re-doing the whole form each time or are you showing/hiding elements one by one?...

Comment: I just used `form.html(...)` and it works perfectly. Thanks for giving me a clue. Have no idea why it was not working before.